# Mercurial no-op merge to preserve history & close branch

Tags: mercurial, merge

[alt text http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/1863/screenshot20091218at112.png](http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/1863/screenshot20091218at112.png)

Revision 107 accidentally merged away all the changes from 100-106

Revision 108 was a hg revert --all -r 106, followed by hg commit, which was probably the wrong thing to do, since instead of merging the branch where I made all the changes, I've encompassed all the changes into one changeset with no description or history.

A) How should I have gone about merging the branch in the first place?

But more importantly:

B) How do I go about merging the branch now?

Comment: what do you mean by "merged away all the changes"? What was your original goal?

Comment: I mean it updated the working copy so that the changes weren't there any more!

Comment: So you merged with the wrong cset ?

Comment: It's Murky: http://bitbucket.org/snej/murky/wiki/Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've not yet pushed the repo anywhere off your box you have an easy fix:

```
   cd ..
   hg clone -r 106 current newcurrent
   cd newcurrent
   hg pull -r 97 ../current
```

now `newcurrent` is a repo that looks exactly like your old one did before 107 and 108 happened.

To merge those two, just do:

```
   hg update  # which gets you to tip
   hg merge   # which merges in the other head and forces you to make choices
```

It's not clear what you did wrong in creating 107, so I don't know how to suggest a change in practice, but it *should* be a simple matter of merging.  Accidentally eliminating all the changes in one branch should have been [hard](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge).

Answer (score 1):

If at all possible, back-up the repository, so that you can experiment safely.

This command will undo the last transaction:

```
hg rollback -h
```

This command might help you to undo your merge and revert:

```
hg backout -h
```

This command will recover your working directory to a previous state without affecting the repository:

```
hg revert -h
```

The -h option in each case gives you the help for the command. Remove the -h option when you are ready to apply the command.

My first experiment would be:

```
hg rollback
hg merge -r 106
```

The plan being to get back to revision 107, which looks like a successful merge of the head containing changesets 95 and 96, and then to merge in the head containing changesets 97, 100 - 106.